# how to know if array only contain numbers or text (both strings)

Tags: php

EDIT: NOT a duplicate, I'm not asking to check for integers, I'm asking for non integers numbers. So it's not.

EDIT2: New script.

---

LAST EDIT (for reference): You're looking for `is_numeric()`. Also, do not use "sanitation", instead use `preg_match()` to make sure it only contains allowed characters (using a regex). This way you can alert the user of invalid characters, plus his/her input won't be modified without his/her knowledge.

---

I'd like to automize the variable declaring/sanitizing process for large forms.

I'm using a list (array) that contains all the elements names of the form so I can loop through them and dynamically declare/sanitize them.

```
$list = array( 'name', '...' );

foreach ( $list as $name ) {
    if ( is_array($_POST[$name]) ) {
        $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY );
        foreach ($$name as $key) {
            // not sure, but i'd do this
            $key = preg_replace('[a-z]', '', $key);
            if ( is_numeric($$name[$key]) ) {
                $$key = (int) $$name[$key];
            } else {
                $$key = $$name[$key];
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( is_numeric($_POST[$name]) ) {
            $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        } else {
            $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        }
    }
}
```

So now, in theory, I can simply use the variable name and have the values of the arrays:

```
$stmt->bind_param('isis', $nums, $texts, $more_nums, $more_texts);
```

In the example, those variables were dynamically generated.

How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnConde Please unmark it as a duplicate, it's not. Thanks.

Comment: Ok found it, `is_numeric()` checks for numbers in strings. Btw, the duplicate system is abusive...